# When is it okay to use sound on webpages?

Tags: html, audio, user-experience

Everybody says the rule is "No sound on webpages", and they have some very good reasons for that.

**But, are there cases where sound is okay?** Either background music\sound or sounds for, say, button presses?

**And on what kind of page?** (On an art portfolio site? On a movie website?)

**When?**  (After user allows it? Only while the user has the tab up?)

**And what kind of sounds?** (Quiet music? Gentle background noise? Click noises?)

**EDIT:** I'm more of asking about when it will add to an existing design, rather than when it's a primary function of the  website. (Like a music streaming site.)

Comment: should probably be moved to ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: if (musicStreamingWebsite); play sound; else mute; end

Comment: **Only** when the user clicks "Play Sound".

Answer (score 3):

on a radio website where you can listen to the radio stream!

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. :) I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Yay for radio (but I'm probably biased!)

Answer (score 1):

The only case when sound should be enabled is **when and only when the user manually enables it or is expecting it (redirected to streaming audio, etc)**. Any other time you will seriously piss your users off.

Comment: Yes. But when do they expect it? For instance, many movie websites autoplay sound, but you sorta expect that from a movie website now.

Comment: pretty much when the point of going to the site is to hear/listen to that multimedia that possibly contains audio. eg, youtube, hulu, a band's website, etc. and even then, there is no autoplay.

Answer (score 1):

When your user is blind and a sound will help him/her use your site / application.

I would say a no across the board on the rest. MAYYYYBE if the user turned it on, but I bet you it would never happen.

Answer (score 0):

All sounds are annoying (mainly because I listen to my on music), except cases where I wan't them to be - games/video/music. And maybe in some artsy design portfolios made completely in flash, but those still are annoying sounds :)

Comment: Amen. Making the computer go "plink!" when you hover over an option is not impressive.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that using sound is always a bad idea since users usually do not expect any sound and it might be very problematic especially when the user is browsing during night. If you decide that you need sound then it's best to make an obvious and quick way for the user to turn it off and make soft starts as opposed to unexpected high volume "booms". One case when sound is ok could be intro movies that movie/game sites use. In such case its fine to auto-play it, but in other cases sounds should be played only on user demand